# Magento Migration Redirects to the old Server

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

I moved my magento installation to a new server. I copied all the files,folders and mysql dump to the new server. I configured local.xml to set the new database settings. When i tried the ipaddress in the browser it took me to the default apache page with magento favicon. So I gave to 777 permissions to all the files and folder (I know its wrong). Now When i try the IPaddress in the brower it redirects me to the old magento server link.Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Did your change the base url in the database? Does the `var` folder exist?

Comment: @Marius cleared the cache folder. I didnt change the base url

Comment: Well...change the base url in `core_config_data`. Search for the records with the value `like` your old url an change them

Comment: @Marius can i give ipaddress as value?

Comment: @Marius I changed still it redirects to the old site

Comment: Clear the cache. (contents of var/cache). If still doesn't work it means you changed the wrong settings

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11000/discussion-between-prem-anand-and-marius)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to update the base url.

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newhost.com/" WHERE path="web/unsecure/base_url";
UPDATE core_config_data SET value="https://newhost.com/" WHERE path="web/secure/base_u
```

replace "newhost.com" with your domain name.

And added in the httpd.conf file

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride all
```

inside the directive that says

```
'<Directory "YOUR DOCUMENT ROOT HERE">'
```

You can find the httpd.conf file in */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* or */etc/apache2/httpd.conf* for linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve your issue?

If not make sure also that public_html/app/etc/local.xml is pointing at the right database
Also check your .htaccess for any line concerning your old server, I say this because i had same issue and it was because on root/.htaccess file I had forgoten to edit 'SetEnv PHPRC /home/*NEWUSER*/public_html'

Answer (score 1):

If you tried all steps still it redirects on old IP address and you are using magento 1.9.0.1
than check your database. some time it creates two database one with #-prefix and other one root. Now need to update new IP address in root database

```
web/secure/base_urel and web/unsecure/base_url.
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache from `var/cache` directory.

after that run this query in `core_config_data` table in Magento. After that you'll not get redirect error.

This process ll work for both Magento 1.9.x and Magento 2.x

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://example.com/" WHERE path="web/unsecure/base_url"; UPDATE core_config_data SET value="https://example.com/" WHERE path="web/secure/base_url"
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem 
try what i did :

**Step 1:**

romove cache with **SSH** :

```
rm -rf /var/tmp/magento/*
```

**Step 2:**

**PS:** In order to use the Magento Connect Manager you may have to reset the PEAR configuration settings. To do this, simply remove the file `downloader/pearlib/pear.ini`, and a new one will be created automatically.

**Step 3:**

**RESET FILE PERMISSIONS**

To make sure that all javascript files, CSS, and images load correctly, you should reset the file permissions to the recommended settings for your new server.

Run the following commands from your Magento root directory (e.g. public_html):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```